# Synology swap hard drive size

Tags: network-attached-storage, synology

I have a Synology DS212, with 2 1TB drives.

I'd like to purchase two 5TB drives (a lot cheaper now), right now I am only using 700GB on a RAID 0. Whats the best way to copy the data over to the new 5TB drives?

I was thinking, can I just take out one of the existing 1TB and replace it with a 5TB and just rebuild?. Once rebuilt swap out the other 1TB, would that work?

Thanks!

Comment: Before you swap out the droves, make sure the 212 will support the 5TB drives.

Comment: @rex I didn't even think of that, it supports 6TB total (two 3TB hard drives). http://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/QIG/DiskStation/12-year/DS212j/Syno_QIG_2bay_enu.pdf thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a RAID0, no you can't just take one out because it will contain half of your data (RAID0 is striped, not mirrored).  If you were on a RAID1 (mirrored), then what you said might work.  Does your DS212 have an external USB port?  If so, you may be able to do something with that.

Answer (score 0):

**[RAID0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_0) requires all its member drives**! If you take out one drive, your data will not be there anymore in either place. There is no "rebuilding" a RAID0 because there is no redundancy.

You should copy the data to another location, possibly an external drive. Then reconfigure your Synology with the new drives. Then copy the data back. When you are reconfiguring you would have your data stored in two places - the external drive, and the original 2 1TB drives which could be put back in if really needed.

As a side note, I recommend you maintain a backup copy of it if it is important data. That means you'd need another method of storing the same, possibly large, amount of data. With 2 drives in RAID0, you are doubling your chance of failure.